# Expresion Regular para sustituir (VIV6a=1 or VIV6b=1) and (CONTAR("A3";"13")=0 or CONTAR("A3";"14")=0)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Tengo esta esta sintaxis:

```
(VIV6a=1 or VIV6b=1) and (CONTAR("A3";"13")=0 or CONTAR("A3";"14")=0)
```

alguna expresion regular que me obtenga lo siguiente:

```
(VIV6a=1 or VIV6b=1) and ( =0 or =0)
```

Para c#

La idea es poder cambiar la expresion para sustituir otra palabras diferentes a 'CONTAR'

Ayuda Por Favor ...

Comment: Lo unico que necesitarías sería buscar por CONTAR + parentesis + texto + parentesis?

Comment: si quieres crear expresiones regulares puedes utilizar esta web 
http://txt2re.com/   es facilde entender ojala sea lo que buscas

Comment: Ok amigos voy a probar ...

Answer (score -1):

Esta Regular Expression debería hacer el trabajo:

```
CONTAR\(.*?\)
```

- `CONTAR\(` Literal, escapando el paréntesis
- `.*` Cualquier caracter
- `?\)` La primer ocurrencia del paréntesis escapado

Ver demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D6TMDX

Comment: oK #hardkoded voy a probarla ... en mi codigo

Comment: SI funciono #hardkoded a la perfeccion gracias ....

Comment: amigo como le puedo decir que excluya lo que tenga dentro de comillas (" ") ? por ejemplo para este caso: << Contar("A3";"14")=0 and VIV6b=1 >>

Comment: Que resultado queres obtener?

Comment: #hardkoded ya no ya pude amigo, queria que excluyera "A3";"14", pero ya encontre la expresión regular, no hay problema gracias por la ayuda ...